# linux to linux screen streaming through wifi

Tags: linux-mint, video, streaming

** **WHY AM I ASKING THIS** **

I have a good powerful laptop at my job, but it has a really bad monitor, the company is getting me new one, but until then I just cannot work. My eyes hurt so bad. Although my own laptop has a good monitor, sadly, it's too weak for development. So I decided to take my laptop to work and stream the screen to my own computer cause there seems to be no other options.

** **ACTUAL QUESTION** **

Is there a tool in linux(I have mint 18.1 Cinnamon) whith which I could stream(through Wi-Fi) screen to another computer with the same OS? Both monitors have same resolution. If any additional info needed about laptops pls comment.

Comment: You can't get a separate external display? With streaming you are bound to get some (noticeable) latency, especially if you keep your keyboard and mouse plugged to the streaming laptop. For remote use, depending on your requirements and environment, perhaps something like [X11 forwarding](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Shell#X11_forwarding) is sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just SSH into the powerful laptop, forward X, and use your lower-power machine as keyboard/monitor/mouse?

Start individual applications, or start a new X server on your local and set your `$DISPLAY` to be that one, and launch an entire desktop session (ie, `mate-session`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [project](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) is what you are looking for. Since you have told that you develop software I guess that is going to be an easy install

Good luck with your screens :)

Answer (score 0):

Either uses X forwarding via `ssh`, or, if you do need the whole screen, have a look at [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) (available as ready-to-install packages in most distros).